# Oracle Query from multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle

1. Determine the amount of total profit generated by the book purchased on order 1002. Display 
   the book title and profit. The profit should be formatted to display a dollar sign and two 
   decimal places.

ZJLB_ORDERITEMS contains ORDER#, ISBN

ZJLB_BOOKS contains ISNB, TITLE, RETAIL, COST

```
SELECT ISBN
FROM ZJLB_ORDERITEMS
WHERE ORDER# = '1002';
```

(then I get an output of 8843172113)

```
SELECT TITLE,
       TO_CHAR(RETAIL - COST, '$99,999.99') "Profit"
FROM ZJLB_BOOKS,
WHERE ISBN = '8843172113';
```

(then I get the Title I want)

but I need to combine two scripts together because I can't manually find the ISBN first, then input `WHERE ISBN = '8843172113'`;

Can I first output the value of ISBN found in script to X then in the script 2, Where ISBN= X (previous result).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JOIN](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm) clause:

> An SQL join clause combines records from two or more tables in a
>   database

Try this:

```
SELECT A.ISBN, B.TITLE, TO_CHAR(B.RETAIL - B.COST, '$99,999.99') "Profit"

FROM ZJLB_ORDERITEMS A JOIN ZJLB_BOOKS B

ON A.ISBN = B.ISBN

WHERE A.ORDER# = '1002';
```

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) for the join concept.